# Getting error while using grunt-cdnify

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, cdn

I am using [grunt-cdnify](https://github.com/callumlocke/grunt-cdnify) for CDN my web assets. I am using below configuration as mention in REMADME.md file.

```
 cdnify: {
  makeItAws: {
    options: {
      base: 'http://my.cdn.com/'
    },
    files: [{
      expand: true,
      cwd: '<%= app.dist %>',
      src: '**/*.{css,html,js}',
      dest: '<%= app.dist %>'
    }]
  }
},
```

My grunt task register

```
grunt.registerTask('build', [
'clean:dist',
'wiredep',
'useminPrepare',
'concurrent:dist',
'autoprefixer',
'concat',
'ngAnnotate',
'copy:dist',
'cdnify',
'cssmin',
'uglify',
'filerev',
'usemin',
'htmlmin',
'cdnify' 
]);
```

I am getting this below error

```
Anjums-MacBook-Pro:project anjum$ grunt cdnify
Running "cdnify:makeItAws" (cdnify) task

Warning: An error occurred while processing a template 
(Cannot read property 'dist' of undefined). Use --force to continue.

Aborted due to warnings.


Execution Time (2015-02-08 08:42:51 UTC)
loading tasks     3ms  ▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇ 33%
cdnify:makeItAws  5ms  ▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇ 56%
Total 9ms
```

Any idea where I am going wrong? Please direct me. Thanks

Comment: The cdnify task is for rewriting static resource URLs found in your HTML and CSS. Once please check all the urls(CDN) in your app and see whether they are pointing to the correct address or not?

Comment: The `grunt.registerTask('build', ...)` registers a task called 'build', that should be run using `grunt build`. Do you register a task called `grunt.registerTask('cdnify', ...)` ?

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a problem with cdnify, it's because your config variable "app" is undefined. Make sure you define app correctly in the config section in your gruntfile, for example:

```
grunt.initConfig({
    pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),

    app: {
      dist: 'dist'
    },
    etc...
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps some tasks are missing on your local npm packages, try

```
npm install
```

To install the packages from you `package.json` file, then try `grunt cdnify` again

Answer (score 0):

To run a task as `grunt cdnify` you must register a `cdnify` grunt task as

```
grunt.registerTask('cdnify', [
    'cdnify' 
]);
```

on your `Gruntfile.js`